# Jquery have a parent div have the same width and height of it's child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm having this problem to solve for weeks now and really need help.

I have this system where a user selects a template with 2 types of areas. One for inserting images and one for inserting text.
Each template may come with numerous areas to insert images and each image area is just a div with it's own dimensions [width px - height px] within a limited area of 800px - 650px.

I will call this div to receive images `div.img`

Inside that `div.img` theres an `input type="file"` and throw jquery.form.js plugin I'm able to insert a new image into it.

I will call the inserted image `new.img`

This `new.img` comes wrapped in a div `div.newImg` because I had to have a button to delete the image on top of the image itself.

I'm using jquery ui draggable and resizable so the `div.newImg` may be resized and dragged inside of `div.img`.

Here are the different elements: `div.img` ->  `div.newImg` -> `new.img` + button delete

HTML

```
<div class="child" style="z-index: 70; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px; height: 172px; cursor: default; background-color: rgba(254, 202, 64, 0.701961);" alt="reset">
   <div class="imgh ui-resizable ui-draggable" alt="reset3" style="height: 100%; width: 204px;">
      <img src="###" style="width:inherit; height:inherit;  min-width:50px; min-height:50px;" class="img_set">
      <div class="close"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.imgh').resizable({ containment: $(this).closest('.child') });
$('.imgh').draggable({ containment: $(this).closest('.child'), scroll: true, snap: true, snapTolerance: 5 });
```

This is what I've manage to approach so far but doesn't help me at all

```
if($('.child').width() > $('.child').height()){
    $('.imgh').height('100%');
    $('.imgh').width($('.imgh img').width());
}else{
    $('.imgh').width('100%');
    $('.imgh').height($('.imgh img').height());
}
```

I've managed to have the `img.img_set` have the same dimensions as it's parent by having `style="width:inherit; height:inherit;"`.

What I need is a way for the `div.imgh` to have the same dimensions as it's inner `img.img_set`. Like a reversed `inherit`.

UPDATE
This code does what I want but my problem is that everytime I resize it comes back to what I've defined in the initialization:

```
if($('.child').width() > $('.child').height()){
    $('.imgh').height('100%');
    $('.imgh').width('auto');
}else{
    $('.imgh').width('100%');
    $('.imgh').height('auto');
}
if($('.imgh').width() > $('.imgh img').width()){
    $('.imgh').width($('.imgh img').width());
}
```

Is there a way for this to only happen once to each `div.imgh`?

Comment: A floated or absolutely positioned block element, with height and width set to `auto` will automatically expand to its contents. So, you might be able to achieve this purely with CSS?

Comment: I've already set it to auto and it exapands width 100% inside of the `div.child` and I can't seem to find the reason why

Comment: Did you float it or set it to `position: absolute`? `div.imgh` could be positioned `absolute` and no width specified. It would then expand to it's contents (child).

Comment: yes, I have `.imgh{ position: absolute; top:0; cursor: move;  overflow: hidden;}` even if I don't set a width, it expands 100%

Comment: [`What I need is a way for the div.imgh to have the same dimensions as it's inner img.img_set`](http://jsfiddle.net/Aqq9Z/). Isn't that what is accomplished in this fiddle (I added red background to `.imgh` so you can better see it's dimensions.

Comment: I've updated the code with something that helped me

Comment: @crush I'm going to create a jsfiddle to facilitate the understanding of this problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use .bind() to resize it it every time something changes...

```
$('.imgh').bind('resize', FullWidthHeight); //Note: check the 'resize' event is relevant to imgh

function FullWidthHeight() {
    $('.imgh').css('height', img.img_set.height());
    $('.imgh').css('width', img.img_set.width());
}
```